# Magento 2 Import categories using csv

Tags: magento2, category, import, csv

I have around 500+ categories in my csv.

I'm trying to import only categories using csv.

Can anyone knows how to import only categories in magento 2 using csv?

Comment: Have you get solution of import export categories ?

Comment: I am also facing issue in export categories. Could you please let me know if you have get any solution of export categories in csv? 
your help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [link](https://www.pearlbells.co.uk/import-magento-2-categories-programmatically/) to import categories from csv programmatically.

**Step by step explanation**

1. Initialise Script
2. Read CSV data
3. Import magento 2 categories

**Initialise Script**
Create a file named `bulkimportcategory.php` inside the script folder.For importing category images copy the images to the `pub\media\catalog\category` folder.

```
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
 
include('../app/bootstrap.php');
$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
 
$url = MagentoFrameworkAppObjectManager::getInstance();
$storeManager = $url->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
$storeId = $storeManager->getStore()->getStoreId();
```

**Read data from CSV**
This step read the data from the sample CSV file and create an array.

```
function getProducts()
{
    $file = 'csv/products.csv';
    $arrResult = array();
    $headers = false;
    $handle = fopen($file, "r");
    if (empty($handle) === false) {
        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
            if (!$headers) {
                $headers[] = $data;
            } else {
                $arrResult[] = $data;
            }
        }
        fclose($handle);
    }
    return $arrResult;
}
```

**Import magento 2 categories programmatically**

The following code iterate through the array and create the magento 2 categories programmatically.

```
/**
 * Import categories to Magento
 *
 * @param $arrResult
 */
function importCategories( $arrResult, $objectManager, $storeId )
{
 
    $parentId = '2';
    $list = array();
 
    foreach ( $arrResult as $import_category ) {
        
        try {
            
            $enabled = ( strtolower( $import_category[16] ) == 'true' ) ? 1 : 0;
            $parentId = ( $import_category[1] == 0 )? '2' : $list[$import_category[1]];            
            
            $url = strtolower($import_category[2]);
            $cleanurl = trim(preg_replace('/ +/', '', preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9 ]/', '', urldecode(html_entity_decode(strip_tags($url))))));
            $categoryFactory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory');
            /// Add a new sub category under root category
            $category = $categoryFactory->create();
            $category->setName(ucfirst($import_category[2]));
            $category->setIsActive( $enabled );
            $category->setUrlKey($cleanurl);
            $category->setData('description', strip_tags($import_category[11]));
            $category->setMetaTitle(trim($import_category[5]));
            $category->setMetaDescription(trim(strip_tags($import_category[6])));
            $category->setMetaKeyword(trim($import_category[7]));
            $category->setParentId($parentId);
            $mediaAttribute = array ('image', 'small_image', 'thumbnail');
            $category->setImage( $import_category[6], $mediaAttribute, true, false);// Path pub/meida/catalog/category/
            $category->setStoreId($storeId);
            $rootCat = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($parentId);
            $category->setPath($rootCat->getPath());
            $category->save();
            $list[$import_category[0]] = $category->getId();
            echo 'Category ' . $category->getName() . ' ' . $category->getId() . ' imported successfully' . PHP_EOL;
        } 
        catch (Exception $e) 
        {
            echo 'Something failed for category ' . $import_category[2] . PHP_EOL;
            print_r($e);
        }
    }
    return $list;
 
}
```

**Sample CSV Data :**

```
ID,ParentID,Name,top,columns,sort_order,Image,date_added,date_modified,language_id,seo_keyword,description,meta_description,meta_keywords,store_ids,layout,Status
100,0,Jewellery Boxes,,,,data/100-0-jewelleryboxes.jpg,,,,Jewellery Boxes,,,,,,TRUE
106,100,Leatherette Boxes,,,,data/106-100-leatheretteboxes.jpg,,,,Leatherette Boxes,,,,,,TRUE
```

Comment: can you please tell me the sample format of csv?

Comment: I have updated the answer with the sample CSV data. save it in categories.csv

Comment: @Ronak Did this help you ?

Comment: @nikin Please check this question and gives solution if you have idea.

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/277997/magento-2-how-to-import-export-categories-in-csv-via-backend-using-entity-type

Answer (score 0):

As per your requirement, you can check out this - https://store.webkul.com/magento2-category-bulk-upload.html

This will help you to import and export a bulk number of categories on the store.