# Magento 2: How to import export Categories in csv via backend using Entity Type catalog_category

Tags: magento2, category, csv, magento2.3.1, importexport

I have to need import export categories in csv same as product, in Magento 2 provided same thing for product.

I have tried below code but facing issue in Model file path `Vendor/CategoryImportExport/Model/Export/Category.php` here need to categories data and after generate csv but I can't getting that details.

I have added Entity Type `catalog_category` in `etc/export.xml` for `Category` and it's displaying fine in Entity Type Dropdown.

> File path: magento/app/code/Vendor/CategoryImportExport/etc/export.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_ImportExport:etc/export.xsd">
    <entity name="catalog_category" label="Category" model="Vendor\CategoryImportExport\Model\Export\Category" entityAttributeFilterType="catalog_category"/>
    <fileFormat name="csv" label="CSV" model="Magento\ImportExport\Model\Export\Adapter\Csv" />
</config>
```

> File path:
>   magento/app/code/Vendor/CategoryImportExport/Model/Export/Category.php

```
class Category extends \Magento\ImportExport\Model\Export\Entity\AbstractEntity
{    
    public function export()
    {
        //Execution time may be very long
        set_time_limit(0);

        $writer = $this->getWriter();
        $page = 0;
        while (true) {
            ++$page;
            $entityCollection = $this->_getEntityCollection(true);
            $entityCollection->setOrder('entity_id', 'asc');
            $entityCollection->setStoreId(Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID);
            $this->_prepareEntityCollection($entityCollection);
            $this->paginateCollection($page, $this->getItemsPerPage());
            if ($entityCollection->count() == 0) {
                break;
            }
            $exportData = $this->getExportData();
            if ($page == 1) {
                $writer->setHeaderCols($this->_getHeaderColumns());
            }
            foreach ($exportData as $dataRow) {
                $writer->writeRow($this->_customFieldsMapping($dataRow));
            }
            if ($entityCollection->getCurPage() >= $entityCollection->getLastPageNumber()) {
                break;
            }
        }
        return $writer->getContents();
    }    
}
```

Any have idea how to import export Categories in csv then let me know.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: have you got any solution for above? I am stuck in same way for customer

Comment: Yes I have fixed the issue. Please check answer.

Comment: Okay, thanks for sharing your answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have fixed issue to update the `export()` function code.

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\CategoryImportExport\Model\Export;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Collection;
use Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import;
use Magento\Store\Model\Store;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Category as ProductEntity;

class Category extends \Magento\ImportExport\Model\Export\Entity\AbstractEntity
{
/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\FileFactory
 */
protected $fileFactory;

/**
 * CSV Processor
 *
 * @var \Magento\Framework\File\Csv
 */
protected $csvProcessor;

/**
 * @var DirectoryList
 */
protected $directoryList;

/**
 * Category collection factory
 *
 * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory
 */
protected $_categoryCollectionFactory;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category
 */
protected $_categoryHelper;

/**
 * Product collection factory
 *
 * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory
 */
protected $_productCollectionFactory;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory
 */
protected $_categoryFactory;

/**
 * Attributes that should be exported
 *
 * @var string[]
 */
protected $_bannedAttributes = ['media_gallery'];

/**
 * Array of supported product types as keys with appropriate model object as value.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $_productTypeModels = [];

/**
 * Product collection
 *
 * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory
 */
protected $_entityCollectionFactory;

/**
 * Product collection
 *
 * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection
 */
protected $_entityCollection;

/**
 * Items per page for collection limitation
 *
 * @var int|null
 */
protected $_itemsPerPage = null;

/**
 * Header columns for export file
 *
 * @var array
 * @deprecated 100.2.0
 */
protected $_headerColumns = [];

/**
 * @var \Magento\ImportExport\Model\Export\ConfigInterface
 */
protected $_exportConfig;

/**
 * @var \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface
 */
protected $_logger;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\ProductFactory
 */
protected $_productFactory;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute\Set\Collection
 */
protected $_attrSetColFactory;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Collection
 */
protected $_categoryColFactory;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection
 */
protected $_resourceModel;

/**
 * @var \Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\ResourceModel\Stock\ItemFactory
 */
protected $_itemFactory;

/**
 * @var Collection
 */
protected $_optionColFactory;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Attribute\Collection
 */
protected $_attributeColFactory;

/**
 * @var \Magento\CatalogImportExport\Model\Export\Product\Type\Factory
 */
protected $_typeFactory;

/**
 * Provider of product link types
 *
 * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\LinkTypeProvider
 */
protected $_linkTypeProvider;

/**
 * @var \Magento\CatalogImportExport\Model\Export\RowCustomizerInterface
 */
protected $rowCustomizer;

/**
 * Attributes codes which shows as date
 *
 * @var array
 * @since 100.1.2
 */
protected $dateAttrCodes = [
    'custom_design_from',
    'custom_design_to'
];

/**
 * Attributes codes which are appropriate for export and not the part of additional_attributes.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $_exportMainAttrCodes = [
    'all_children',
    'available_sort_by',
    'children',
    'children_count',
    'custom_apply_to_products',
    'custom_design',
    'custom_design_from',
    'custom_design_to',
    'custom_layout_update',
    'custom_use_parent_settings',
    'default_sort_by',
    'description',
    'display_mode',
    'filter_price_range',
    'image',
    'include_in_menu',
    'is_active',
    'is_anchor',
    'landing_page',
    'name',
    'name',
    'url_key',
    'url_path',
];

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface $localeDate,
    \Magento\Eav\Model\Config $config,
    \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resource,
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
    \Magento\ImportExport\Model\Export\ConfigInterface $exportConfig,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\ProductFactory $productFactory,
    \Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute\Set\CollectionFactory $attrSetColFactory,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory $categoryColFactory,
    \Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\ResourceModel\Stock\ItemFactory $itemFactory,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Option\CollectionFactory $optionColFactory,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Attribute\CollectionFactory $attributeColFactory,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\LinkTypeProvider $linkTypeProvider,
    \Magento\CatalogImportExport\Model\Export\RowCustomizerInterface $rowCustomizer,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory $categoryCollectionFactory,
    \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category $categoryHelper,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\FileFactory $fileFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\File\Csv $csvProcessor,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList $directoryList,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory $categoryFactory,
    array $dateAttrCodes = []
) {
    $this->_entityCollectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
    $this->_exportConfig = $exportConfig;
    $this->_logger = $logger;
    $this->_productFactory = $productFactory;
    $this->_attrSetColFactory = $attrSetColFactory;
    $this->_categoryColFactory = $categoryColFactory;
    $this->_resourceModel = $resource;
    $this->_itemFactory = $itemFactory;
    $this->_optionColFactory = $optionColFactory;
    $this->_attributeColFactory = $attributeColFactory;
    $this->_linkTypeProvider = $linkTypeProvider;
    $this->rowCustomizer = $rowCustomizer;
    $this->_categoryCollectionFactory = $categoryCollectionFactory;
    $this->_categoryHelper = $categoryHelper;
    $this->dateAttrCodes = array_merge($this->dateAttrCodes, $dateAttrCodes);

    $this->fileFactory = $fileFactory;
    $this->csvProcessor = $csvProcessor;
    $this->directoryList = $directoryList;

    $this->_categoryFactory = $categoryFactory;
    $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;

    parent::__construct($localeDate, $config, $resource, $storeManager);
}

/**
 * Get header columns
 *
 * @return string[]
 */
public function _getHeaderColumns()
{
    return $this->_customHeadersMapping($this->rowCustomizer->addHeaderColumns($this->_headerColumns));
}

/**
 * Get entity collection
 *
 * @param bool $resetCollection
 * @return \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb
 */
protected function _getEntityCollection($resetCollection = false)
{
    if ($resetCollection || empty($this->_entityCollection)) {
        $this->_entityCollection = $this->_entityCollectionFactory->create();
    }
    return $this->_entityCollection;
}

/**
 * Get items per page
 *
 * @return int
 */
protected function getItemsPerPage()
{
    if ($this->_itemsPerPage === null) {
        $memoryLimitConfigValue = trim(ini_get('memory_limit'));
        $lastMemoryLimitLetter = strtolower($memoryLimitConfigValue[strlen($memoryLimitConfigValue) - 1]);
        $memoryLimit = (int) $memoryLimitConfigValue;
        switch ($lastMemoryLimitLetter) {
            case 'g':
                $memoryLimit *= 1024;
            // fall-through intentional
            case 'm':
                $memoryLimit *= 1024;
            // fall-through intentional
            case 'k':
                $memoryLimit *= 1024;
                break;
            default:
                // minimum memory required by Magento
                $memoryLimit = 250000000;
        }

        // Tested one product to have up to such size
        $memoryPerProduct = 500000;
        // Decrease memory limit to have supply
        $memoryUsagePercent = 0.8;
        // Minimum Products limit
        $minProductsLimit = 500;
        // Maximal Products limit
        $maxProductsLimit = 5000;

        $this->_itemsPerPage = (int)(
            ($memoryLimit * $memoryUsagePercent - memory_get_usage(true)) / $memoryPerProduct
        );
        if ($this->_itemsPerPage < $minProductsLimit) {
            $this->_itemsPerPage = $minProductsLimit;
        }
        if ($this->_itemsPerPage > $maxProductsLimit) {
            $this->_itemsPerPage = $maxProductsLimit;
        }
    }
    return $this->_itemsPerPage;
}

/**
 * Set page and page size to collection
 *
 * @param int $page
 * @param int $pageSize
 * @return void
 */
protected function paginateCollection($page, $pageSize)
{
    $this->_getEntityCollection()->setPage($page, $pageSize);
}

/**
 * Export process
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function export()
{
    //Execution time may be very long
    set_time_limit(0);

    $writer = $this->getWriter();
    $page = 0;
    while (true) {
        ++$page;
        $entityCollection = $this->_getEntityCollection(true);
        $entityCollection->setOrder('entity_id', 'asc');
        $entityCollection->setStoreId(Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID);
        $this->_prepareEntityCollection($entityCollection);
        $this->paginateCollection($page, $this->getItemsPerPage());
        if ($entityCollection->count() == 0) {
            break;
        }
        $exportData = $this->getExportData();

        $fileName = 'catalog_category.csv';
        $filePath = $this->directoryList->getPath(\Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::VAR_DIR). "/" . $fileName;

        $categoryCollectionData = $this->getCategoryCsvData($exportData);
        $this->csvProcessor
            ->setDelimiter(',')
            ->setEnclosure('"')
            ->saveData(
                $filePath,
                $categoryCollectionData
            );

        return $this->fileFactory->create(
            $fileName,
            [
                'type' => "filename",
                'value' => $fileName,
                'rm' => true,
            ],
            \Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::VAR_DIR,
            'application/octet-stream'
        );
    }
    return $writer->getContents();
}

protected function getCategoryCsvData($exportData)
{
    $result = [];
    $exportCategoryData = $exportData;

    $storeId = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId();

    $result[] = [
        'category',
        'parent',
        'description',
        'is_active',
        'include_in_menu',
        'url_key',
        'meta_title',
        'meta_keywords',
        'meta_description',
        'is_anchor',
        'default_product_listing_sort_by',
        'image',
        'display_mode',
        'landing_page',
        'custom_design',
        'position',
        'page_layout',
        'custom_design_from',
        'custom_design_to',
        'custom_use_parent_settings',
        'custom_apply_to_products',
        'custom_layout_update',
        'store',
        'path'
    ];
    foreach ($exportCategoryData as $csvData) {
        $result[] = [
            isset($csvData['name']) ? $csvData['name'] : '',
            isset($csvData['parent_id']) ? $csvData['parent_id'] : '',
            isset($csvData['description']) ? $csvData['description'] : '',
            isset($csvData['is_active']) ? $csvData['is_active'] : '',
            isset($csvData['include_in_menu']) ? $csvData['include_in_menu'] : '',
            isset($csvData['url_key']) ? $csvData['url_key'] : '',
            isset($csvData['meta_title']) ? $csvData['meta_title'] : '',
            isset($csvData['meta_keywords']) ? $csvData['meta_keywords'] : '',
            isset($csvData['meta_description']) ? $csvData['meta_description'] : '',
            isset($csvData['is_anchor']) ? $csvData['is_anchor'] : '',
            isset($csvData['default_product_listing_sort_by']) ? $csvData['default_product_listing_sort_by'] : '',
            isset($csvData['image']) ? $csvData['image'] : '',
            isset($csvData['display_mode']) ? $csvData['display_mode'] : '',
            isset($csvData['landing_page']) ? $csvData['landing_page'] : '',
            isset($csvData['custom_design']) ? $csvData['custom_design'] : '',
            isset($csvData['position']) ? $csvData['position'] : '',
            isset($csvData['page_layout']) ? $csvData['page_layout'] : '',
            isset($csvData['custom_design_from']) ? $csvData['custom_design_from'] : '',
            isset($csvData['custom_design_to']) ? $csvData['custom_design_to'] : '',
            isset($csvData['custom_use_parent_settings']) ? $csvData['custom_use_parent_settings'] : '',
            isset($csvData['custom_apply_to_products']) ? $csvData['custom_apply_to_products'] : '',
            isset($csvData['custom_layout_update']) ? $csvData['custom_layout_update'] : '',
            isset($storeId) ? $storeId : '',
            isset($csvData['path']) ? $csvData['path'] : ''
        ];
    }
    return $result;
}

/**
 * Get export data for collection
 *
 * @return array
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.NPathComplexity)
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedLocalVariable)
 */
protected function getExportData()
{
    $exportData = [];

    $isActive = true;
    $level = false;
    $sortBy = false;
    $pageSize = false;

    try {
        $collection = $this->_categoryCollectionFactory->create()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->setStore($this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId());
        // ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active','1');
        foreach ($collection as $index => $value) {
            $categoryIdProduct = $value->getEntityId();

            $categoryId = $categoryIdProduct;
            $category = $this->_categoryFactory->create()->load($categoryId);
            $exportData[$index] = $value->getData();
        }
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $this->_logger->critical($e);
    }
    return $exportData;
}

/**
 * Clean up already loaded attribute collection.
 *
 * @param \Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute\Collection $collection
 * @return \Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute\Collection
 */
public function filterAttributeCollection(\Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute\Collection $collection)
{
    $validTypes = array_keys($this->_productTypeModels);
    $validTypes = array_combine($validTypes, $validTypes);
    foreach (parent::filterAttributeCollection($collection) as $attribute) {
        if (in_array($attribute->getAttributeCode(), $this->_bannedAttributes)) {
            $collection->removeItemByKey($attribute->getId());
            continue;
        }
        $attrApplyTo = $attribute->getApplyTo();
        $attrApplyTo = array_combine($attrApplyTo, $attrApplyTo);
        $attrApplyTo = $attrApplyTo ? array_intersect_key($attrApplyTo, $validTypes) : $validTypes;

        if ($attrApplyTo) {
            foreach ($attrApplyTo as $productType) {
                // override attributes by its product type model
                if ($this->_productTypeModels[$productType]->overrideAttribute($attribute)) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        } else {
            // remove attributes of not-supported product types
            $collection->removeItemByKey($attribute->getId());
        }
    }
    return $collection;
}

/**
 * Entity attributes collection getter.
 *
 * @return \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Attribute\Collection
 */
public function getAttributeCollection()
{
    return $this->_attributeColFactory->create();
}

/**
 * EAV entity type code getter.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getEntityTypeCode()
{
    return 'catalog_category';
}
```

}

Comment: Could you please share full script because you have used some function but not giving here.

Comment: Yes I have updated full script please check.

Comment: Okay, thanks for reply.